# Tensorflow install on Windows with anaconda and no internet connection

Tags: windows, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

I can not install Tensorflow on Windows because there in no internet connection based on commpany's security policy.

I just installed anaconda and python by transmiting files with intranet.

Please let me know how to install that with no internet connection.

==========================================================================

In addition, when I used the below command after installing tensorflow, I found
other problems..

```
     Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import tensorflow as tf
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\Daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
     from tensorflow.python import *
   File "C:\Users\Daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
     from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
   File "C:\Users\Daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
     from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
 ImportError: No module named 'google'
```

I don't know how to solve this one.

Comment: Can you just copy over the [.whl file for a pip install](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation_on_windows)? You may need to do something similar for dependencies.

Comment: the file is tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can download the whl file and transfer it to your workstation, then you can run:

`pip.exe install --upgrade --no-deps <tensorflow whl file name>`

This should avoid trying to connect to download tensorflow dependencies, as anaconda already has most of these.

Comment: I did as your answer and I read the message that tensorflow intstalled susessfully. However, when I wirte command "import tensorflow as tf", other error messages was shown.  ImportError: No module named 'google'. So I couldn't use it on python. If you knonw how to solve this problem, please, let me know.

Comment: I think you will need to similarly install all tensorflow dependencies, too. The list of tensorflow dependencies can be see here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow  You can download the protobuf package from pypi directly: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf/3.2.0